# Lambda Cognito User Pool authorizer - can I automatically get the custom user attributes?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I'm using Lambda functions, executed via API Gateway using a Cognito User Pool Authorizer.

I know I can get the "standard" user attributes (like `sub`, `email`, `cognito:username`, etc.) from `event.requestContext.authorizer.claims`.

But this does not include custom user attributes (like `custom:myAttribute`).

I know I can get them via [adminGetUser](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#adminGetUser-property), and this works, but I wonder whether I can save this call and somehow get those custom attributes automatically in the `event`?

Comment: I get event.requestContext.authorizer.claims inside my proxy lambda, how can I get access to event or authorizer object access in http proxy, I want to send the username as a header to my server. Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you already looked at this doc for custom claims?
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-enable-cognito-user-pool.html.
You will need to define context in following manner for custom attributes:

```
{
    "context" : {
        "role" : "$context.authorizer.claims['custom:myAttribute']"
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I assume this means I cannot use the "Lambda Proxy integration"  and I need to write my own body mapping template? 

If yes, is there a standard template I can copy and add my custom attributes to, so that the Lambda function works exactly like before (i.e. with the "Proxy integration")?

Comment: Hmm so I double checked a method with the Lambda proxy integration (bascially unchanged to the scenario I described above), and one with the body mapping template. Turns out there is no difference - both contain the custom attribute in the "authorizer.claims"...

So either I was blind before, or something else has changed.

I will keep monitoring this issue, and update with any new enlightments.

Comment: Update: It is still working like a charm. No idea why it didn't work before.

Answer (score 3):

After you add a custom attribute to a Cognito user pool and assign a value to it for a user there are a couple of reasons why it won't appear in the `requestContext.authorizer.claims` collection.

The first and most obvious is that you need to make the custom attribute readable via the app client you use to generate the ID token you are authenticating with. If you are using the AWS console this is done by navigating to `App Clients -> Show Details -> Set attribute read and write permissions` then tick the attribute(s) you want to make visible to your Lambda.

The second reason for your attribute not appearing, even if you have completed the first step, is that the user's claims are encoded in the ID token you generate. This means that if you're using an ID token created before making the attribute(s) readable you still won't see them. The solution to this is to just generate a new ID token for your user at which point you should see the attributes in your Lambda's request context.

Comment: This was it. Wow. I spent probably 3-4 days searching for this answer. Thank you so much. I wish the docs were more clear that you need to make the custom attributes readable.

Comment: I faced the same issue, it was caused that I the token sent is the `accessToken` not the `idToken` which don't contains the custom attributes